# Connect to Oracle remote Database by only installing a client on my laptop?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to connect to remote oracle database from my laptop if I only install instant client, without installing oracle database? 
I have the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files in oracle_home/network/admin which I created. I downloaded instant client, but how can I connect to the database by sqlcplus client. My system just does not recognize sqlplus command

I also did this

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: And what have you tried to do? If you installed oracle client and you have correct   `tnsnames.ora`, SQL*Plus should work. Also there is an useful utility - `tnsping`, it helps sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

SQL*Plus is not part of the basic Instant Client, it is an additional download at the Instant Client download page. Once you have downloaded and installed it, you can use it by setting the ORACLE_HOME and PATH envrionment variables, for example:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/base/product/11.2.0/client_1
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Or on a Windows OS:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\oracle\base\product\11.2.0\client_1
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```